# how to store drop-down list select into database?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a form for creating projects. It contains 2 foreign keys domain and owner (domain_id and owner_id). in fact these are 2 drop-down lists. when i try to submit the form, and check my database, I found out that owner and domain have NULL as value, eventhough i selected values from the drop-down list.

this is projectController :

```
public function create()
{
    $domains = Domain::all('nameDomaine', 'id');
    $owners = Owner::all('nameOwner', 'id');

    return view('projectss.create', compact('domaines', 'owners'));
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $domain_id = Domain::all()->pluck('nameDomain', 'id');
    $owner_id = Owner::all()->pluck('nameOwner', 'id');
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title'     => 'required',
        'code'      => 'required',
        'domain_id' => 'required',
        'owner_id'  => 'required',
    ]);

    Project::create($request->all());

    return redirect()->route('projects.index')
        ->with('success', 'Project created successfully');

}
```

and this is create.blade.php :

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
   <div class="form-group">
     <strong> Domain : </strong>
     <select class="form-control" name="domain_id">
       @if (!count($domains) > 0)                                  
        <strong>    Whoops! Something went wrong </strong>                          
       @else
        @foreach($domains as $id => $domain)
              <option value="{{ $id }}">{{ $domain->domain }}</option>
        @endforeach
       @endif
     </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
  <div class="form-group">
  <strong> owner : </strong>
  <select class="form-control" name="owner_id">
    @if (!count($owners) > 0)                                   
        <strong> Whoops! Something went wrong </strong>                         
    @else
        @foreach($owners as $id => $owner)
              <option value="{{ $id }}">{{ $owner->nameOwner }}</option>
        @endforeach
    @endif
  </select>
 </div>
</div>
```

I read a lot of posts about this problem, but none of them is working for me.

Comment: You validation passed ? Are your wrapping it inside a form?. is your title and code inserted correctly in database ?

Comment: Yes, validation passed, title and corde are correctly inserted. yes the drop-down lists are inside the form

Comment: Do `Log::info($request->all());` in store function and submit the form check is domain_id & order_id value coming correctly ?

Comment: still have NULL as a value. I also have an other drop-down-list called street, this one got the id=0 eventhought I choose a street with an id defferent then 0

Comment: Do you need 


`$domain_id = Domain::all()->pluck('nameDomain', 'id');`
`$owner_id = Owner::all()->pluck('nameOwner', 'id');`

In the store function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems close but a few tweaks are needed. Also check your Project model and see if there is a $fillable array. If there is you'll need all the fields in your validate call in it e.g.

```
protected $fillable= [
    'title'
    'code'
    'domain_id' 
    'owner_id'
];
```

Remove the calls in your store function.

```
public function create()
{
    $domains = Domain::all('nameDomaine', 'id');
    $owners = Owner::all('nameOwner', 'id');

    return view('projectss.create', compact('domaines', 'owners'));
}

public function store(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request, [
        'title'     => 'required',
        'code'      => 'required',
        'domain_id' => 'required',
        'owner_id'  => 'required',
    ]);

    Project::create($request->all());

    return redirect()->route('projects.index')
        ->with('success', 'Project created successfully');
}
```

Make sure you're adding the right ID.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
   <div class="form-group">
     <strong> Domain : </strong>
     <select class="form-control" name="domain_id">
       @if (!count($domains) > 0)                                  
        <strong>    Whoops! Something went wrong </strong>                          
       @else
        @foreach($domains as $domain)
              <option value="{{ $domain->id }}">{{ $domain->domain }}</option>
        @endforeach
       @endif
     </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
  <div class="form-group">
  <strong> owner : </strong>
  <select class="form-control" name="owner_id">
    @if (!count($owners) > 0)                                   
        <strong> Whoops! Something went wrong </strong>                         
    @else
        @foreach($owners as $owner)
              <option value="{{ $owner->id }}">{{ $owner->nameOwner }}</option>
        @endforeach
    @endif
  </select>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

in controller's store function

```
 $domain_id = Domain::all('nameDomain', 'id');
 $owner_id = Owner::all('nameOwner', 'id');
```

In you view

```
<select class="form-control" name="domain_id">
   @if (!count($domains) > 0)                                  
    <strong>    Whoops! Something went wrong </strong>                          
   @else
    @foreach($domains as $id => $domain)
          <option value="{{ $domain->id }}">{{ $domain->domain }}</option>
    @endforeach
   @endif
 </select>
```

and for second select option

```
<select class="form-control" name="owner_id">
@if (!count($owners) > 0)                                   
    <strong> Whoops! Something went wrong </strong>                         
@else
    @foreach($owners as $id => $owner)
          <option value="{{ $owner->id }}">{{ $owner->nameOwner }}</option>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

You was not fetching id of your object. The `$id` you were fetching will just give you the index.

This should work :)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
@foreach($owners as $id => $owner)
    <option value="{{ $id }}">{{ $owner->nameOwner }}</option>
@endforeach
```

to

```
@foreach($owners as $owner)
    <option value={{ $owner->id }}>{{ $owner->nameOwner}</option>
@endforeach
```

And repeat with the other foreach loop.

If that doesn't work, in your controller add dd($request); to see what info is being passed to it and share with us, please.